# Am I manipulating the content of states when I manipulate a superposition of indices?

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information

I posted this question on quantumcomputing forum but I think maybe is more adequate to cstheory. I'm trying to understand something, I have been reading some papers about Grover's iterator, especially related to pattern matching and I found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340700215_Pattern_Matching_A_Quantum_Oriented_Approach), where they show an exact pattern matching algorithm using "parallel match sliding window". It finds the exact match of  $P$ in $T$ if oracle function $f(i)$ evaluates as $f(i)=1$ (if $T[i+1$ to $i+M-1]=P[0$ to $M-1]$ with high probability. My questions are the next:

-Can I define another oracle like this to solve some other problem and not be careful about the possible realization of it? Or there are considerations about what functions can I define?

-I have a superposition were the basis $B=\{|1⟩,|2⟩,...,|N⟩\}$ is encoding the positions of the elements in a text $T$, with the purpose of measuring the location of the probable solution of a searching problem via Grover's iterator. Can I manipulate this superposition to build some algorithm assuming that in fact, I am dealing with the content of the states and not the positions? I mean, something like pointers?